# Ruby eval string with functions

Tags: ruby, escaping, double-quotes

I am trying to eval the expression:

```
eval "\"1 pages\".gsub(/\D/,'')"
```

It always retrieves `'1 pages'` while I expect only the string `'1'`.

Why does `eval` ignore `gsub`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash since you're in an interpolated string:

```
eval "\"1 pages\".gsub(/\\D/, '')"
```

Or just don't use double-quotes since you don't need interpolation:

```
eval '"1 pages".gsub(/\D/, "")'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `eval` ignore `gsub`?

It does not. It may look so to you because `\D` has no special meaning within double quotes, and hence it is interpreted as plain `"D"`. And there is no `"D"` within `"1 pages"`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape the `D` as well, because that's part of the regex and not the character "D" alone:

`eval "\"1 pages\".gsub(/\\D/,'')"`